# log scale does not display data

Tags: matplotlib, logging, scale

I am new to matplotlib. And I am trying to draw a scatter graph with yscale set to log. The graph does not show any data in the plot:
[image].

It displays following warnings:

> ```
> UserWarning: Attempted to set non-positive ylimits for log-scale axis; invalid limits will be ignored.
> 'Attempted to set non-positive ylimits for log-scale axis
> ```

Can someone help me please?
Here is the code:

```
rawdata = np.genfromtxt("E:\data\Paper\lifetime paper\smoothed and unsmoothed data.csv"
                               ,delimiter=",", unpack=True)

x = rawdata[0]
lifetime_91_unsmoothed = rawdata[1]
lifetime_91_smoothed = rawdata[2]
lifetime_20_unsmoothed = rawdata[3]
lifetime_20_smoothed = rawdata[4]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
# fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)
# fig.set_figwidth(7)
# # fig.set_figheight(12)
ax1.scatter(x,lifetime_91_unsmoothed,marker='s',facecolors='k',s=30,edgecolors='k',
            alpha=0.6,label='Unsmoothed lifetime')
ax1.scatter(x,lifetime_91_smoothed,marker='o',facecolors='r',s=30,edgecolors='r',
            alpha=0.6,label='Smoothed lifetime')
# ax1.scatter((0.5),(0.5),marker='o')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xlim(0,1.01)
ax1.set_ylim(0,1.01)
ax1.set_xlabel('Time [s]',fontsize=12)
ax1.set_ylabel('Normalized intensity', fontsize=12)
ax1.legend(loc=0,frameon=False,fontsize=12)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=12)

plt.show()
```

Comment: you can't set the minimum y-value to 0 on a log scale since `log(0)` is not defined

Comment: Thank you. I set minimum above 0. It is working.