# matplotlib subplots last plot disturbs log scale

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, share, axes

I am making a `matplotlib` figure with a 2x2 dimension where x- and y-axis are shared, and then loop over the different axes to plot in them. I'm plotting variant data per sample, and it is possible that a sample doesn't have variant data, so then I want the plot to say "NA" in the middle of it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_plots_per_fig = 4
nrows = 2
ncols = 2

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex="all", sharey="all", figsize=(8, 6))
axs = axs.ravel()

for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]  # example values, but this list CAN be empty
    bins = 3  # example bins
    if x: 
        ax.hist(x, bins=bins)  # plot the hist
        ax.set_yscale("log")
        ax.set_title(str(i), fontsize="medium")
    else:
        ax.set_title(str(i), fontsize="medium")
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'NA', ha='center', va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)

fig.show()
```

This works in almost every case; example of wanted output:
[image: wanted output]

However, only if the last plot in the figure doesn't have any data, then this disturbs the log scale. Example code that triggers this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_plots_per_fig = 4
nrows = 2
ncols = 2

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex="all", sharey="all", figsize=(8, 6))
axs = axs.ravel()

for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    x = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    bins = 3

    if i == n_plots_per_fig-1:  # this will distort the log scale
        ax.set_title(str(i), fontsize="medium")
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'NA', ha='center', va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
    elif x:
        ax.hist(x, bins=bins)  # plot the hist
        ax.set_yscale("log")
        ax.set_title(str(i), fontsize="medium")
    else:
        ax.set_title(str(i), fontsize="medium")
        ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'NA', ha='center', va='center', transform=ax.transAxes)

fig.show()
```

[image: unwanted_output]

The log scale is now set to really low values, and this is not what I want. I've tried several things to fix this, like unsharing the y-axes for the plot that doesn't have any data `[ax.get_shared_y_axes().remove(axis) for axis in axs]` or hiding the plot `ax.set_visible(False)`, but none of this works. The one thing that *does* work is removing the axes from the plot with `ax.remove()`, but since this is the bottom most sample, this also removes the values for the x ticks for that column:
[image: almost_corret_output]

And besides that, I would still like the name of the sample that didn't have any data to be visible in the axes (and the "NA" text), and removing the axes doesn't allow this.

Any ideas on a fix?

**Edit**: I simplified my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the limits manually with `ax.set_xlim()` / `ax.set_ylim()`.
Note, that if you share the axes it does not matter on which subplot you call those functions. For example:

```py
axs[-1][-1].set_ylim(1e0, 1e2)
```

If you do not know the limits before, you can infer it from the other plots:

```py
x = np.random.random(100)
bins = 10
if bins != 0:
    ...
    yy, xx = np.histogram(x, bins=bins)
    ylim = yy.min(), yy.max()
    xlim = xx.min(), xx.max()
else:
   ax.set_xlim(xlim)
   ax.set_ylim(ylim)
```

Comment: This works for this specific dataset, but my code has to be generic (i.e. I don't know how big the y-values will be). Only setting a lower limit doesn't work either, because this still changes the upper y limit to 1e15 for some reason. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: When I test this, then `ylim = (0, 106)` and `xlim = (0.002344, 1.0)`. This will then give the following error: `UserWarning: Attempted to set non-positive bottom ylim on a log-scaled axis.
Invalid limit will be ignored.` I tried then setting the minimal ylim to 1e0, but this still lets the y-scale start at 1e-2 for some reason.

Comment: Turns out you can't do a minimal ylim of 0 on a log scale ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619056/log-scale-does-not-display-data)). Specifying `ymin=1` does work, but then the lower hist values are not visible anymore, but `ymin=0.1` makes these values too visible.

Comment: what about ymin=0.5?

Comment: I'm not sure how I didn't think of this, but yeah, that look's better. Thanks for your help; I'll accept the answer